# how to select a field form database and assign it to a var?

Tags: php, select, escaping, where-clause

i would like to select a field from a database, escape it, attach it to a var and use it in a javascript lather on

here is what i have:

```
<script>
<?php include("php/connect.php"); 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT user FROM database where username = "user" limit 1");
$escaped_username = mysql_escape_string($username);
?>
var test = <?php $escaped_username ?>
alert (test);
</script>
```

what is not wright?
thanks

Comment: quotes.. use '' instead of "" in `user`, also you need to `echo` the variable..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With mysql_fetch_assoc() you do not have to loop and it gets you the first row.
It is also best to separate PHP and Javascript as much as you can.

```
<?php
  include("php/connect.php");

  // gets one row
  $result = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT username FROM database WHERE username='some_user' LIMIT 1"));
  $username = '';
  if($result !== FALSE) { // if it finds the username in the DB
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($result['username']);
  }
?>

<scritpt type="text/javascript">
  var test = <?php echo $username; ?>
  alert(test);
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You either need to loop through the query using a while loop and mysql_fetch_array, or you could directly access the first row of the query using mysql_result. Also, you were selecting user, not username from database, and the where clause should have used single quotes instead of double.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM database WHERE username = 'user' limit 1"); 
$username = mysql_result($result, 0);
$escaped_username = mysql_escape_string($username);
```

Comment: using `mysql_result()` is slow and should be avoided if at all possible. It's much easier to do `$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); echo $row['username']` instead. Especially since queries that fetch only one field/row from the DB tend to be a rarity compared to multi-row/multi-column result sets.